# Derivation of the transformation rules for vielbein and spin connection

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

I have been taking a course on General Relativity. Recently, I was given the following homework assignment, which reads

> Derive the following transformation rules for vielbein and spin connection:
> $$\delta e_a^\mu=(\lambda^\nu\partial_\nu e_a^\mu-e_a^\nu\partial_\nu\lambda^\mu)+\lambda_a^b e_b^\mu$$
> $$\delta\omega_a^{bc}=\lambda^\mu\partial_\mu\omega_a^{bc}+(-e_a^\mu\partial_\mu\lambda^{bc}+\omega_a^{d[b}\lambda_d^{c]}+\lambda_a^d\omega_d^{bc}).$$

I was instructed to use:
$$[M_{ab},X_c]=X_{[a}\eta_{b]c}$$
and
$$[M_{ab},M^{cd}]=-\delta_{[a}^{[c}M_{b]}^{d]}=-\delta_a^c M_b^d+\delta_b^c M_a^d+\delta_a^d M_b^c-\delta_b^d M_a^c.$$
Also, the professor told us to consider the covariant derivative
$$\nabla_a=e_a^\mu\partial_\mu+\frac{1}{2}\omega_a^{bc}M_{cb}$$
To be honest, I have no idea what these symbols are (after examining my GR lecture note carefully). And most frustratingly, even if I have taken a one-year course on differential geometry (mathematical rigor), I still know nothing about the covariant derivative above. What on earth do these symbols stand for? Is there any standard textbook that can help a GR beginner like me? I came here for some advice, please.

Comment: You may want to examine, e.g., [arXiv:1106.2037](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2037).

Comment: See, e.g., section 1.6 of https://www.amazon.com/Ideas-Methods-Supersymmetry-Supergravity-Gravitation/dp/0750305061

Comment: It's vierbein instead of vielbein to do with the German for four, 'vier'

Comment: Just realized that there is also "vielbein" from 'viel' German for 'many'